# Recursive Query - Updating recursive folder structure name with T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that stores files for a file share program. The table, "FileSystem", stores both files and folder structure. The FileSystem table has an "IsFolder" field that tells if this is a file or a folder. The "ParentId" represents the parent folder of the file or folder. For example:

```
Id  ParentId    Name        RelativePath    IsFolder
----------------------------------------------------
1   NULL        \           \               1
2   1           Test        \Test           1
3   2           Folder1     \Test\Folder1   1
4   2           myFile.txt  \Test\Folder1   0
```

If I update the name of "Test" folder to "Test2" I would like to update the RelativePath text of all applicable folders.

```
Id  ParentId    Name        RelativePath    IsFolder
----------------------------------------------------
1   NULL        \           \               1
2   1           Test2       \Test2          1
3   2           Folder1     \Test2\Folder1  1
4   2           myFile.txt  \Test2\Folder1  0
```

I've tried using a CTE but the performance is really slow. It is entirely possible I am using bad TSQL though!

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FileSystem]
(
    [FileSystemId] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [VARCHAR](500) NULL,
    [RelativePath] [VARCHAR](1000) NULL,
    [IsFolder] [BIT] NOT NULL,
    [ParentId] [INT] NULL,
    [LastWriteTime] [DATETIME] NULL,
    [FileData] [VARBINARY](MAX) NULL,
    [UploadedBy] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [BIT] NOT NULL,
    [DeletedTime] [DATETIME] NULL,
    [DeletedBy] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [DocumentType] [VARCHAR](10) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_FileSystem] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([FileSystemId] ASC)
                    WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FileSystem] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_FileSystem_IsDeleted] DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsDeleted]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FileSystem] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_FileSystem_FileSystem] 
        FOREIGN KEY([ParentId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[FileSystem] ([FileSystemId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FileSystem] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_FileSystem_FileSystem]
```

This is the CTE I've tried but it takes 20 seconds to run.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        t.FileSystemId,
        t.ParentId,
        t.Name as RootPath,
        t.RelativePath,
        t.IsFolder
    FROM
        FileSystem AS t
    WHERE  ParentId is null
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        t.FileSystemId,
        t.ParentId,
        CAST(REPLACE(CTE.RootPath+'\'+t.Name,'\\','\')AS VARCHAR(500)) AS RootPath,          
        t.RelativePath, 
        t.IsFolder
    FROM
        FileSystem AS t
        JOIN CTE
            ON CTE.FileSystemId=t.parentId
    WHERE
        t.IsFolder=1 AND t.FileSystemId IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT 
    CTE.RootPath,  CTE.RelativePath, CTE.FileSystemId
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
   CTE.ParentId IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Do you only need the `RelativePath` field to speed up access (apart from that it seems to be redundant as the path can be constructed by following the parent chain) or do you store anything else there?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it is a required field for a system we have in place.

Comment: Your CTE recalculates **all** relative paths, but you only need those, that have the changed ID in their parent chain.

Comment: Yes, but when I pick a specific folder, say "Folder1" in my example above, it does not get the root element. It just returns Folder1 instead of \Test\Folder1.

Answer (score 0):

Super rookie mistake but I didn't realize there was no index on my ParentId. I'm leaving the question posted in case the CTE is helpful for anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code and let me know if you need any other changes.

```
Declare @tbl as table
(id int
,ParentId int
,Name varchar(100)
,RelativePath varchar(100)
,isFolder bit
)

insert into @tbl

Values(1,null,'\','\',1)
,(2,1,'Test','\Test',1)
,(3,2,'Folder1','\Test\Folder1',1)
,(4,2,'Myfile.txt','\Test\Folder1',0)

update @tbl
set Name='Test2' where Name='Test'

update @tbl
set RelativePath=REPLACE(RelativePath,'Test','Test2')
where RelativePath like '%Test%'

select * from @tbl
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you do not repeat the paths in the hierarchy, you don't need a recursive query because `relativepath` has the information you need:

```
update filesystem
    set relativepath = (case when relativepath like '%\Test\%'
                             then replace(relativepath, '\Test\', '\Test2\'
                             else concat(left(relativepath, len(relativepath) - len('Test')),
                                         'Test2'
                                        )
                        end)
    where concat('%\', relativepath, '\%') like '%\Test\%';
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I cannot guarantee that a RelativePath might not repeat. For example: \Test\Folder1\Test is possible. Also, I would like to utilize this when a new record is added and I want to build the RelativePath.